# Is there a general way to define models for different forms (perhaps using inheritance/some other method)?

Tags: django, python-3.x, mysql-5.7

Is there a way to have a general template like structure (similar to parent-child classes in python), so that we can define functions and processes without writing down relatively similar code multiple times for the different forms?

I am working on a project where we want to efficiently design 10-15 forms for a website that users will fill multiple times. The previous architecture was not made meticulously and so, is very clunky (has a lot of code duplication, etc).

These forms do not have the same number/name of fields. As an example, there could be a form "student" and another form "flowers", the point here being that the two forms are unrelated.

Both of these forms have different fields, student may have "name", "parent", "job of parent", while flowers may have "scientific name" and "medicinal uses". Let's say all fields in student are related to "name" and all fields in flowers are related to "scientific_name".

Is there a way to define a parent model, that defines this general structure, and then inherit both of these tables from there (the field names have to be different)?

Willem Van Onsem suggested ModelForms for this which fits well, except that I want to be able to have a template field for name "name template" in the parent class, which I could rename "name" when I use it for "student" and "scientific name" when I use it for flower. The reason why I want to do this is so that I can define general functions in the parent class, which I need to perform essentially the same operation in the both the forms.

I couldn't figure out a way to do that.

Comment: Looks like a [`ModelForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So, a model form would allow me to create a child class with fields picked up from the parent class. What I had in mind was the ability to have a template field for name "name template" in the parent class, which I could rename "name" when I use it for "student" and "scientific name" when I use it for flower. The reason why I want to do this is so that I can define general functions in the parent class. My question is a little unclear though, so I'm editing it to clarify.